# Why did Hogwarts Library carry a book containing information on horcruxes if it was a banned subject?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, hogwarts

The book I'm talking about is 'Secrets of the Darkest Arts' (which is the only book covering the subject of horcruxes to my knowledge). Riddle presumably read this book prior to him asking Slughorn about them as he already knew what they were (he just wanted information on how to make multiple horcruxes). Anyway, why did they keep the book in the library (although in the restricted section) if it was a banned subject (Slughorn told Riddle the subject was banned when asked about them). Basically any student could have found the book and learned about them.

Comment: 'Secrets of the Darkes Arts' contains explicit information on how to make horcruxes. Dumbledore removed the book from the library later on after Riddle asked Slughorn about them, but by that point the damage was already done.

Comment: I'll accept that. I didn't remember Hermione's quote.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't banned, just *restricted* and placed in the *restricted section*.

Comment: @TylerH Horcruxes were a banned subject, Slughorn told Riddle that when he asked about them. And they didn't want students to know about their existence so it seems strange that they kept the book as students are allowed to browse the restricted section (and virtually any student could've sneaked in and gotten their hands on it if they really wanted to).

Comment: @silverpaw From the first book we know what happens when a student tries to sneak into the Restricted Section.

Comment: @Scimonster I assume you're referring to the "screaming book", and if so, we don't know if the other books are enchanted. Probably not, as older students are allowed to browse the Restricted Section so it wouldn't make sense if all the books would start screaming if you tried to read them.

Comment: @silverpaw They were probably all enchanted to scream if an unauthorized person opened them.

Comment: @Scimonster Again, older students are allowed to browse and open books in the Restricted Section so it wouldn't make sense if they did.

Comment: @silverpaw Then that older student is authorized and the book will allow itself to be opened.

Comment: @Scimonster Right, so all the books cannot be enchanted then.

Comment: @silverpaw I don't follow you here. What's wrong with saying the books all have a spell on them that allows them to recognize who's authorized and who's not, and scream if opened by an unauthorized person?

Comment: @Scimonster My point is that older students could've gotten their hands on the horcrux book before it was removed (which Riddle most likely did). So they didn't want students to know about the existence of horcruxes but they let the horcrux book lay around for any "authorized" student to pick it up. Makes sense... And again, it's only speculation whether all the books are enchanted. We don't know that.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108856/4918 "Why didn't Dumbledore destroy books on Horcruxes?"

Comment: It was banned later?  Slughorn only says to Tom  that no one would want "...existence in such a form" and that it's very dark. But it's knowledge, probably one of the failed experiments in the pursuit of immortality, so it was preserved and even the Hogw. libraty contained some info on it.

Answer (score 16):

According to Slughorn there may not have been much about Horcruxes in the library to begin with.

> ‘No ... well ... you’d be hard-pushed to find a book at
>   Hogwarts that’ll give you details on Horcruxes, Tom. That’s
>   very Dark stuff, very Dark indeed,’ said Slughorn. - -***Half Blood Prince***

The books that did mention Horcruxes were **removed** from the library, we are just unsure when it occurred exactly.

> ‘And once we get hold of it, how do you destroy a Horcrux?’
>   asked Ron.
>
> ‘Well,’ said Hermione, ‘I’ve been researching that.’
>
> ‘How?’ asked Harry. ‘I didn’t think there were any books on Horcruxes
>   in the library?’
>
> ‘There weren’t,’ said Hermione, who had turned pink. ‘Dumbledore
>   removed them all, but he – he didn’t destroy them.’
>   -***Deathly Hallows***

And again later in the same chapter Hermione states this, showing Slughorn may have been mistaken.

> ‘This is the one that gives explicit instructions on how to make
>   a Horcrux. Secrets of the Darkest Art – it’s a horrible book, really
>   awful, full of evil magic. I wonder when Dumbledore removed it
>   from the library ... if he didn’t do it until he was Headmaster, I bet
>   Voldemort got all the instruction he needed from here.’

We can probably safely assume that when Dumbledore was made Headmaster he would have removed them for sure, but I believe that the fact that Slughorn mentions how strongly Dumbledore was against Horcruxes when speaking to Riddle he may have already removed the books.

> It’s a banned
>   subject at Hogwarts, you know ... Dumbledore’s particularly
>   fierce about it ...’ - ***Half Blood Prince***

Three points to note.

1. We don't know when this ban went into effect in the 1000 years of Hogwarts' existence, before Slughorn's conversation. Dumbledore himself may have been the root cause of the ban.
2. Being a banned subject may only mean it's not **taught** in school, while owning a book that contains details about it in the restricted section of the library for study by advanced students may be, or was, allowed.
3. Finally, Hogwarts is not the only location in which books can be found, and Voldemort likes to cover his trail and keep up his good boy persona (in school), so finding books on Horcruxes outside of school would have appealed to him as well.

Comment: 1. Slughorn told Riddle it was a banned subject when he asked about them, so presumably the ban was already in effect during that time.

Comment: @silverpaw yes, i stated that.

Comment: 2. Yes, but it seems strange to keep the book around if they didn't want anyone (particularly students) to know about them.

Comment: @silverpaw it is weird which is why Dumbledore removed them personally, im simply listing options.

Comment: I know, and I can't help to think that this is a plot hole.

Comment: @silverpaw  banning something and enforcing a ban are to different things. Dippet seems to be an unobservant headmaster he could have simply not cared for forgot, previous head masters may have had the ban thrust on them from the board of directors(or whatever board ran the school) but not supported the ban hence leaving the books, so we really cant say definitively if its a plot hole or not

Comment: @silverpaw dealing with anything pre slughorns conversation is all speculation, my answer lays out that at least dumbledore thought they should be removed, and offered you a few reasons why they potentially were not removed pre dumbledore.

Comment: On second note: also banned subjects are taught in school. Unforgivable curses are banned but 'barty crouch jr. moody' tells in the first lesson that he shouldn't be showing the curses until 7. grade. So Hogwarts teaches the curses but it is still forbidden to use them

Comment: Additionally, it is mentioned that 'Secrets of the Darkest Art' contained information on things other than Horcruxes which could have been enough to land it in the restricted section instead of removing it all together. I could see a Horcrux-only book being removed but a book where Horcruxes are only one chapter in the book being kept around with tighter access restrictions.

Comment: I feel it's a stretch to argue that Dumbledore being so against Horcruxes (as if anyone else wasn't so dead set against them) would have removed them before being headmaster. What makes you think he would even have the right to do that? And where would he have stored them if they were put in the headmaster office? It's also a stretch to say just because Slughorn believed there wouldn't be any books in the library doesn't mean there weren't; with the way he acted later - deathly ashamed - you can imagine he probably would have wanted to believe there weren't any books but is that reality?

Answer (score 7):

Books in the restricted section are, as we see in *Chamber of Secrets*, not usually available to students. They need express permission in writing from a teacher for every book they want to access:

> ‘Er – Professor Lockhart?’ Hermione stammered. ‘I wanted to – to get this book out of the library. Just for background reading.’ She held out the piece of paper, her hand shaking slightly. ‘But the thing is, it’s in the Restricted Section of the library, so I need a teacher to sign for it – (…)’
>
> (…)
>
> Madam Pince held the note up to the light, as though determined to detect a forgery, but it passed the test. She stalked away between the lofty shelves and returned several minutes later carrying a large and mouldy-looking book.
>
> (*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, chapter *The rogue Bludger*)

Apparently, Amando Dippet and his predecessors believed that to be sufficiently safe. It wasn’t before Dumbledore had become Headmaster (*after* Riddle had asked Slughorn about Horcruxes) that the books about Horcruxes were removed from the library altogether.

Comment: Yes, but it seems strange that they kept the book around if they didn't want anyone to know about horcruxes. It would've been more logical to remove the book immediately after the subject was banned.

Comment: @silverpaw: The place to be for library books is in the library. It’s highly unusual for serious (scientific) libraries to destroy a book or magazine, ever; even for dangerous books (say, describing how to make certain poisons or how to construct a bomb), it’s considered enough to place them in a ‘poison cabinet’, i.e. a restricted section.

Comment: Well, obviously it wasn't enough as Riddle found the book and obtained information about horcruxes. And any student could've done the same thing.

Comment: @silverpaw: Did you read what I wrote? “Students need express permission in writing from a teacher for every book they want to access.” Now, Riddle is a master in social engineering; certainly not “any student” could have done the same.

Comment: Students can sneak into the restricted section without permission. Harry did it during his first year (although he was wearing the invisibility cloak). Maybe it does require some skill without being detected but many students could've done the same.

Comment: @silverpaw As we saw, there are enchantments on the books in the Restricted Section that prevent unauthorised reading - we know they can scream, and no doubt there are other defences on the worst volumes; Madam Pince is known to be fiercely protective of her books. Harry's invisibility cloak is literally the best in the world, and the teachers who were awake were mostly distracted with trying to steal or protect the Philosopher's Stone. I doubt there are more than a handful who could manage it, and few of them would be inclined to actually try it.

Comment: @anaximander We don't know if all the other books are enchanted. As you're probably aware, older students are allowed to browse the Restricted Section (with or without permission from a teacher we don't know for sure), so the books cannot all be enchanted, it wouldn't make sense. The Restricted Section is not as well protected as you're trying to make it out to be.

Comment: Just because older students can browse the shelves doesn't mean the books aren't enchanted - it just means that the enchantment knows when a reader isn't allowed to be reading the book. An upper-year student reading book on making horcruxes is likely similar to a Muggle forensics student reading a book that could tell them how to commit the perfect murder, or a chemical engineering student reading a book that talks about mixing explosives: dangerous in the wrong hands, but *surely* these students can be trusted? After all, for them to actualy *do* it would be unthinkable...

Comment: Students aren't even supposed to know about the existence of horcruxes, let alone how to make one, so it really doesn't make sense that they would let the horcrux book lay around for any upper-year student to pick it up and obtain this information.

Answer (score 1):

## Others may not be as ‘fierce’ as Dumbledore.

Horcruxes were considered a banned subject at Hogwarts during Voldemort’s time as a student, which may have been in no small part due to Dumbledore’s influence there.

> “But all the same, Tom … keep it quiet, what I’ve told – that’s to say, what we’ve discussed. People wouldn’t like to think we’ve been chatting about Horcruxes. It’s a banned subject at Hogwarts, you know … Dumbledore’s particularly fierce about it …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

Previous headmasters may not have felt as strongly as Dumbledore, and left the books for educational purposes. The degree to which subjects are banned likely depends on the headmaster’s judgement - when Dumbledore became headmaster, he removed the books referencing Horcruxes entirely. The previous headmasters may have simply not seen the need for this specific measure.

Answer (score 0):

Although it was a banned subject, it was in the restricted section where students weren't allowed to dawdle around.

Comment: Students are allowed to browse the restricted section so pretty much anyone could've gotten their hands on the book, which seems strange as it they didn't want students to know about the existence of horcruxes.

Comment: students could not browse the restricted section without permission from their teachers.

Comment: We don't know if that rule applies to older students, but even if it did, students can sneak in anyway so we know that the "permission" thing can be circumvented.