# Who has access to the Restricted Section of the Hogwarts Library?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Who was permitted to be in the Restricted Section? If the books were not to be read by students why not place the books in a more secure location, perhaps the headmaster's office etc. Or were certain students allowed to borrow books from the Restricted Section with the permission of a teacher?

**So did certain students have access to the restricted section?**

*This is a different question to the [one posed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135572/why-did-hogwarts-library-carry-a-book-containing-information-on-horcruxes-if-it) by 'silverpaw', asking what is highlighted in bold.*

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Restricted_Section - *It is possible that after students reach a certain age, they no longer need a signed note to access the Restricted Section, as in her sixth year Hermione Granger says she's "been right through the restricted section" when looking for information on Horcruxes, and as it is unlikely any professor would give her a note to research a banned subject at Hogwarts, it is likely she didn't need one [nor did] Tom Riddle from roughly 50 years earlier, when he too was researching on Horcruxes in the same section at about the same age as Hermione.*"

Comment: didn't we see evidence of needing instructor permission to get into the restricted section? The note allows you in the section. Does that not answer the question? Or are you asking if some students had a blanket, all access type pass?

Comment: @Valorum, What you just commented would classify as an acceptable answer, if you had wished to post there.

Comment: @LordSalizar - Nah. Copying and pasting from the wiki ain't my style.

Comment: @NKCampbell - I think it's pretty clear that they're asking if certain students (those above a certain age, for example) no longer needed a pass.

Comment: @LordSalizar he has, all of the reputation money can by

Comment: No more comments needed, I have the answer to my question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**; Students appear to be able to get permission to browse the restricted section at later years, not just to check out specific books. Permission does appear to be needed from a teacher even at later years. Idiotic teachers also appear to give permission to young students with no recourse.

> Harry wandered over to the Restricted Section. He had been wondering
>   for a while if Flamel wasn’t somewhere in there. Unfortunately, you
>   needed a specially signed note from one of the teachers to look in any
>   of the restricted books and he knew he’d never get one. These were the
>   books containing powerful Dark Magic never taught at Hogwarts and **only**
>   **read by older students** studying advanced Defence Against the Dark
>   Arts. - ***Philosopher stone***(emphasis mine)

This quote heavy implies that has an older Student with permission can look at any book in the restricted section, and need not get note by note approval for each book.

This would fit in nicely for both Hermione and Riddle who were both top of their class and could easily have obtained such access in later years to further their studies.

As year 2 students attempting to get a restricted book, it was most likely better for Hermione to get said specific book listed on her note to not bring too much suspicion down on herself.

> There was only one way to get out a book from the Restricted
>   Section: You needed a signed note of permission from a teacher. -
>   **Chamber of Secrets**

Again it never specifies the note need include the book title.

In year 4 Harry seems to get a note from Professor McGonagall that allowed him to browse in the restricted section

> So Harry, thinking that he would soon have had enough of the
>   library to last him a lifetime, buried himself once more among
>   the dusty volumes, looking for any spell that might enable a
>   human to survive without oxygen.However, though he, Ron
>   and Hermione searched through their lunchtimes, evenings and
>   whole weekends – though Harry asked Professor McGonagall for
>   a note of permission to use the Restricted Section, and even
>   asked the irritable, vulture-like librarian, Madam Pince, for help
>   – they found nothing whatsoever that would enable Harry to
>   spend an hour underwater and live to tell the tale. -***Goblet of Fire***

This shows he had no idea what book he needed, so it was most likely a blanket permission to browse.

Comment: Good answer. One nitpick "Again it never specifies the note need include the book title." It doesn't, but when Hermione asks Lockhart for permission, she says "I wanted to - to get this book out of the library" and then Ron exclaims "I don't believe it, he didn't even *look* at the book we wanted." Which heavily implies the usual process, and the note, specifies a specific book. When they give the note to Madam Pince she reads it. "'*Moste Potente Potions?*' she repeated suspiciously"

Comment: Of course, Madam Pince needs to know the book in order to fetch it for them, but she certainly seems to care about the title, as well as the signature.

Comment: @Au101 the restricted section does not appear to only be accessible via madam prince fetching it for you only, in year 4 harry appears to be actively searching the restricted section as does hermione jn year 6, only in year 2 did it appear she had to fetch it. Most likely because it was a specific note and book. In year one its simple just a small rope that seperates the restricted section from the rest of the books not behind her desk locked up.

Comment: Years 2 are also prob never given permission so she's probably suspicous of a lockhart sig for a potions book

Comment: Well I think that's it though, isn't it? In later years you can browse freely (presumably NEWT students only), we assume. Harry got permission to browse freely in 4 because he was a champion, so a special case was made. But before then, you need a signed note and it would usually be for a specific book, or some specific books, which Madam Pince will go and get for you. You're right that the barrier to the restricted section does not appear to be very substantial, but presumably you get in trouble if you're spotted in there as a younger student

Comment: @Au101  like i said in the answer we dont know 1 way or the pther for sure in later years kf you need a note or not, but harry getting a blanket permission in year 4 means that we know at least blanket permission exists and hermiome having it in year 6 just confirms that, but leaves it being due to age or students maturity in question

Answer (score 1):

http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Restricted_Section -

> It is possible that after students reach a certain age, they no longer
>   need a signed note to access the Restricted Section, as in her sixth
>   year Hermione Granger says she's "been right through the restricted
>   section" when looking for information on Horcruxes, and as it is
>   unlikely any professor would give her a note to research a banned
>   subject at Hogwarts, it is likely she didn't need one [nor did] Tom
>   Riddle from roughly 50 years earlier, when he too was researching on
>   Horcruxes in the same section at about the same age as Hermione."

Answer (score 0):

## Some students are permitted to peruse it.

Certain students are seemingly allowed to read books in the restricted section without needing to get a teacher’s permission or request a specific book. In her sixth year, Hermione looked through the entire restricted section, including the books with extremely dark magic, for information on Horcruxes.

> “Meanwhile, the Hogwarts library had failed Hermione for the first time in living memory. She was so shocked, she even forgot that she was annoyed at Harry for his trick with the bezoar.
>
> ‘I haven’t found one single explanation of what Horcruxes do!’ she told him. ‘Not a single one! I’ve been right through the restricted section and even in the most *horrible* books, where they tell you how to brew the most *gruesome* potions – nothing! All I could find was this, in the introduction to *Magick Moste Evile* – listen – “of the Horcrux, wickedest of magical inventions, we shall not speak nor give direction” … I mean, why mention it, then?’ she said impatiently, slamming the old book shut; it let out a ghostly wail. ‘Oh, shut up,’ she snapped, stuffing it back into her bag.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 18 (Birthday Surprises)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, certain students, either by virtue of their age or by being trusted enough by the Hogwarts staff, can get access to the entire restricted section.