# How did Tom Riddle first find out about Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

How did Tom Riddle find out about what Horcruxes were and what they did before he asked Horace Slughorn?

Hermione wasn't about to find a single thing about them in the library when Harry brought it up and she had never heard of them prior. Where else would Tom have heard of them?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135572/why-did-hogwarts-library-carry-a-book-containing-information-on-horcruxes-if-it/135573#135573

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155853/how-did-slughorns-information-on-horcruxes-actually-help-voldemort/155854#155854

Comment: im strongly leaningon closing as a dupe of the second link, op asks why the book was at hogwarts that taught voldemort, but i show in my answer he may not have learned from said book, and it answers your question as much as we know at least.